# How to search in Mail.app within Gmail Chat history?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I setup Mail.app to pull GMail data . I realized that I cannot search within my GoogleTalk chat history. Is there a way or a hack to get the chat history to my folders that get pulled as well so that my search results will include information from Chat as well.

Comment: If google talk is federated with jabber, you could start using iChat but mail can only follow rss or imap/exchange/pop. If you can get an RSS feed of your chat, that might be your only option

Comment: Have you configured GMail and Apple Mail for IMAP or POP access?

Comment: I just selected to configure mail from 'Gmail' . It uses IMAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zevlag is right. You're not going to be able to do precisely what you were after (true IMAP syncing of chat logs). But here's a couple of things that you can:

First, you could download your chat logs using this method: http://freshhorse.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/leaving-gmail-and-bringing-your-chats-with-you/

- This will take quite a bit of time and I doubt you'd want to do it over and over to keep your logs up-to-date. But it will allow you to have an easily searchable record of your chats on your local machine (Spotlight).

Second you could look into Google's APIs for a way to get at your chats. Here's one example of a script attempting this:

https://gist.github.com/1051628

- This will be even more complicated and still won't get you what you're after but if your a bit of a hacker you might be able to put something together with the API that would keep your local record up-to-date.

Sorry there isn't a way to do just what you want.

-Samuel

Comment: Great find @samuel I wish someone could use the shared gist to write a thunderbird extension.

Comment: Too bad https://freshhorse.wordpress.com/ has been marked private by its owner :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  It was *partially* possible once a time, but has been discontinued due to not working properly.

http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-POP-and-IMAP-en/msg/31a22885e3e9ed57